# How can I write a makefile suffix rule that will apply an optional patch

Tags: makefile, patch

In a makefile (I have GNU Make 3.82), assume I have a suffix rule set up like this:

```
.a.b:
    a_to_b $<
```

Now, say I want to apply a patch to the generated .b file. I can do this:

```
.a.b:
    a_to_b $<
    patch -p0 < $*.patch
```

However, if there isn't a patch for every .b, how can the patch step be made conditional on the presence of a .patch file so that any .b with a patch available gets the patch applied but any other .b is left as it is once a_to_b completes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is apply the patch if it exists, you can just change your rule to something like:

```
.a.b:
        a_to_b $<
        [ ! -f $*.patch ] || patch -p0 < $*.patch
```

However, likely you also want to have the rule fire if the patch file has changed, even if the .a file has not changed.  In that case you'll have to switch to pattern rules, and write two: one with the patch prerequisite and one without:

```
%.b : %.a %.patch
        a_to_b $<
        patch -p0 < $*.patch

%.b : %.a
        a_to_b $<
```

Comment: I was actually seeking your first answer, but I much prefer your second answer. I've implemented it and it works great.